# Routing and CORS (laravel and backbone(ajax))

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I can't fetch the URI my data is routed to. I get a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

I read this article http://acairns.co.uk/2013/01/routing-and-cors-with-laravel-4/

He mentions a few ways to get it to work, but only one method worked for me. The one that is not an ideal method.

```
Route::resource('players', 'PlayersController');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

The above works for me, but here is why this is bad "*this is such a bad idea. This means that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is outside a route and will be set with every request*" I obviously don't want that.

I tried his solution and it does not work, I'll show you my attempts below. Maybe I didn't implement it the right way?

Adding inside filters.php

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->afterFilter(function($response)
        {
            $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            return $response;
        });
    }
});
```

I tried just adding it inside my routes.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->afterFilter(function($response)
    {
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;
    });
}
```

I am not sure if I am adding it into the right place, I think I am. If I am then its not working.

So are there any methods I can try to receive the data without getting that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so before asking this I am pretty sure I tried this, maybe I was moving to fast or something, but using this inside the `after` filter works! FYI: this is located in the `filters.php` inside the /app directory :)

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

I got that from this https://twitter.com/dhrrgn/status/288385113442623489

So far I am able to consume that response with no problems, yay!

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't now the header bound to every view? Doesn't it work if you add it as a filter to only the one route?

Comment: I tried it, and it would not work, the author of this post says the same thing http://acairns.co.uk/2013/01/routing-and-cors-with-laravel-4/ this post suggest's to do what I did above. I am a laravel noobie, but in my mind since this is inside the filters.php it doesn't bind to every view, just on the response. I really don't know if what I am saying is right, but that's how it works in my mind. All is working now, if you have sufficient proof this is wrong I would be glad to find another solution. As for now on-ward and up-ward!

Comment: Actually I re-read your comment, I am not really sure how to add it as a filter to one route. Would I run Route::filter(); or something? I watched a tutorial on this, but I am not sure. IDK it works now, thats what matters I guess :)